# Find every occurence of string in a file and store it in a List

Tags: java, string, file

I'm working on a program, that will find every occurence of a texture name in a file and then store it's name in a List. So lets say, that i have a text file with string that looks like this:

> {"sampletext":"urlDistortion":"textures/Noises/FX_GaussianNoise_10x.png","sample text sample text "url":"textures/shader/shader_test/FX_Noise_Wispy_Dense.png","urlGradient":"textures/gradients/sparks.png","blendMode": "sample text","urlMask":"textures/shader_test/FX_Radial_Grad.png"}

Every texture name starts with "textures and then goes it's location which ends with quotation mark in example "textures/gradients/sparks.png".

Now i want to extract the file name and store it in a list, so from the first occurence which is "textures/Noises/FX_GaussianNoise_10x.png" i'll get just this "FX_GaussianNoise_10x.png" part. I came with an idea, that i'll create pattern that will find "textures", skip the location and somehow copy the remaining filename part.

```
try {
        File file;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("textures/");
        List <String> textureNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (File f : list) {
           file= f.getAbsoluteFile();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

                String line = scanner.nextLine();

                Matcher matcher = p.matcher(line);

                while (matcher.find()){
                //and here i would like to add this texture name to my list and 
                continue searching for the next occurence
                }

                System.out.println("found " +count);

                }
            }
        }
```

I know that there is a start() method in a Matcher class, which returns the start index of the previous match so i could do something like this inside the while loop

```
String s = line.substring(matcher.start(),)
```

and then just add this to the list, but I don't know how could i specify the endIndex.

If anyone knows how can i do it, or if there is a better way to achieve this i'll be grateful for help.

Comment: *Better way:* 1) Learn regex (which is what `Pattern` uses). --- 2) Write a regex that matches the entire path from `textures/` up to but excluding the `"`. --- 3) Have the regex capture the file name as a capturing group. --- 4) Do the `find()` loop and get the file name by calling `group(1)`.

Comment: *FYI:* Don't use `Scanner` for simple line-reading, use a `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Something like `Pattern.compile("\"(textures/[^\\"]*)\"")` could work. Alternatively, since your file appears to be JSON, you could consider using a JSON parser.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, really great idea with capturing group. I know that there should be regex, but creating this one causes me a lot of trouble. There is something wrong with this one from @Erik, it causes an error. And my files are .awp

Comment: Yes, it looks like I'm missing a back-slash -- try `Pattern.compile("\"(textures/[^\\\"]*)\"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple test case that shows an idea for your inner loop:

```
@Test
public void testParse() {
    String line = "{\"sampletext\":\"urlDistortion\":\"textures/Noises/FX_GaussianNoise_10x.png\",\"sample text sample text \"url\":\"textures/shader/shader_test/FX_Noise_Wispy_Dense.png\",\"urlGradient\":\"textures/gradients/sparks.png\",\"blendMode\": \"sample text\",\"urlMask\":\"textures/shader_test/FX_Radial_Grad.png\"}";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(textures/[^\\\"]*)\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("found " + m.group(1));
    }
}
```

It produces this output:

```
found textures/Noises/FX_GaussianNoise_10x.png
found textures/shader/shader_test/FX_Noise_Wispy_Dense.png
found textures/gradients/sparks.png
found textures/shader_test/FX_Radial_Grad.png
```

Comment: Is there a quick way to get now just a filename from this pattern? I.e. FX_GaussianNoise_10x.png from first output?

Comment: You can have nested groups, for example `Pattern.compile("\"(textures/[^\"]*?([^\"/]+))\"")`  -- everything after the last `/` will be captured in `m.group(2)`